# Data validation based off a table

Tags: excel

I am trying to automate the data entry process which takes place in excel (Mac 2016)

Basically I want to create a bunch of dropdown in some sheets so people don't have to type everything.

The issue is that there is this huge table with data something like this:

```
Region  State  District  City
A1      1      Dis1      Ci1
A1      1      Dis1      Ci2
A1      1      Dis2      Ci3
A1      2      Dis3      Ci4
A1      2      Dis4      Ci5
A2      3      Dis4      Ci6
```

So in a new sheet: if I select Region as "A1" (cell A2), then I need cell B2 with dropdown as "1","2" and similarly for District and City.

I know the standard method is multiple tables with a vertical list of option and using "Data validation" and "Indirect", but I don't know how to go about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you can adapt some functionality offered by VLOOKUP() function see the example here [VLOOKUP() function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: I know the vlookup, but can i have the value as a drop down

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for [Select Drop Down Item and use VLOOKUP to Return Multiple Attributes](http://www.excel-university.com/select-drop-down-item-vlookup-return-multiple-attributes/)